# CSS selector suggestion needed

Tags: html, css

I am making a box with background color in it and lots of content over it
for that I have to change text color off all texts inside box opposite to background color
i have used `filter:invert(98%)` now the problem is it is working good but making other images and icons inverted as well

**main thing**

now I wanted to select only elements with text with css since I am working with wp react for blocks
I don't have much control with js so css solution is required for that thing

**note that there are lots of elements inside main element in real project with various names**

here is a example code below

```css
.main {
background:black;
}

.main > * {
filter:invert(80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class"text1">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets conta
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class"another_text">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets conta
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.main > *`  this select all elements chidren of main. For example you can add a class `.filter{ filter:invert(98%) }` and add it where you need

Comment: actually i am not so good with css and looking for something which will select elements with text only if there is anyway

Comment: Isn't it easier to set the text-color? Like `.main{color: #fff}`? If you don't set it in any content, all children of `.main` will inherit the text-color.

Comment: You have a typo also in your divs class="text1".

Comment: Dou you really want to invert the text? For instance `#ff0000` (bright red) inverted is `#00ffff` (cyan). Don't know if I would stay around long on a site that has cyan text on red background.

Answer (score -1):

it's simple, you can write css this way as well
.main{
background:

```css
span{
color:white;
padding:4%;
background:#000000ad
}
```

```html
<div class="test"><span>Hello World</span></div>
```

}

Comment: This will give **all** the `<span>` on the entire page this text-color and background. Don't suppose OP wants that. And what if there's a `<div>` or `<p>`  or whatever other tag is inside that div? Then this won't work.

Comment: You can add class on the tag and apply css on that class only